# How can I listen for a presented card in .NET MAUI app using internal serial port?

Tags: android, serial-port, maui

I have purchased this device [external link](https://www.ruggedi.com/latest-new-arrival-rugged-smartphone-with-lf-134-2khz-rfid-reader-built-in.html) in order to read card number whenever a card is presented to the inbuilt 125 kHz card reader.

Preinstalled, there is an java application (to which I was provided with source code) which can read the number and display it.

Based on that, I have created a .NET MAUI application that can connect to the internal port **/dev/ttyS1** and start to listen for received data. It uses the System.IO.Ports library.

My MAUI application works great and whenever I present a 125 kHz card, I can see its number. BUT when I restart the mobile device and launch my application, no data is received upon presenting the card. I have to start the preinstalled application, then I can quit it, launch my application and only then my MAUI application starts to listen for data.

Since I am not a Java programmer, I do not know, what I am missing that the preinstalled application does have and mine does not.

One thing I noticed in the Java application source files is this piece of code in the onResume method:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("shmaker.android.intent.action.OPEN_DONE");
filter.addAction("shmaker.android.intent.action.CLOSE_DONE");
filter.addAction("shmaker.android.intent.action.STATE_REFRESH");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Can this have something to do with my issue? How can I replicate this in my .NET MAUI app?

Comment: When do you expect it to read this when your application is closed/killed?

Comment: No, only when my application is active in the front

Comment: And that does not always work, Have you tried debugging in both scenarios and tried to narrow it down to what could be causing this? And its probably the code in OnResume causing the issue for you, Why don't you add this in your app?

Comment: I have tried debugging both. The method from port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived) does not fire when the preinstalled Java application is not launched first.
No errors in the debug console.

You can see that in the onResume, there are some libraries from "shmaker.android" namespace tha are implemented only in Java.

Comment: Come on, no intent should be needed. I am simply in my application and I am registering the handler to receive data whenever anything is present at the serial port buffer. I do not want the application automatically launched from anywhere.

Comment: When you Resume there are times when you need to reconfigure the intents, this could be the issue you are facing may be

Comment: But I do not think I am resuming since I am launching my application for the first time. I tried to add overriden OnResume events to the MAUI solution but they were not fired.

Comment: I see, my bad well then in this case I would recommend you create a Github project that replicates your issue this could be a possible bug with MAUI

Comment: You may be right. I was fighting with this simple task for some time. I was also forced to use <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="9.0.0-alpha.1.24058.11" /> in alpha version to get it working.
I will make GitHub example, do you think I should submit it then to the MAUI development team?